# Suggest me phone with removable battery

Tags: smartphones

Please suggest me phone with these requirements:

Removable battery

Dual sim

4 GB RAM or more

Available extended battery not less than 8Ah

Available bootloader unlocking

Exclude LG V20

Comment: Have you looked into the ASUS ROG Phone 2?
"Only" 6000 mAh, but since it's a modern CPU it should perform relatively well.
Removable batteries are pretty much only found on budget / low-range phones these days in my experience.

Comment: Thanks, this is really good phone, but I don't really like phones with OLED screens because of permanent retention (burn-in)

Answer (score 3):

I think the only one which fits all the requirements is the [Moto E6 Plus.](https://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_moto_e6_plus-9831.php) The 64Gb variant has 4GB of RAM, a removable battery, dual-sim and has known methods for unlocking the bootloader.

The only point I'm not sure is available extended batteries, but afaik no existing phone has a 8Ah extended battery. You are better off using an external battery with USB charging.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer. But it's still not answered. I have LG V20 with 10.5 Ah battery.

Comment: The Moto E6 Plus does have 5Ah extended battery cases. But... I highly doubt your case has a true capacity of 10500mAH. It would have to be huge?

Comment: 22mm thickness but it's very comfortable to hold in hand because of bowl for cameras. The only thing I don't like, PUBG is lagging. It's label capacity, not true.

Comment: The E6 plus is supposed to run PUBG correctly, albeit at lower graphics settings. But it is still a mid-range phone so don't expect all games to run well.

Comment: I see. Sad that there are no better phones than LG V20 or this with removable battery.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want a removable battery? The reason phone manufacturers has gone away with that is to improve the waterproofing and durability of the phones. To MY knowledge (as an Apple phone user), I don't know of any.

Comment: Because I can use extended battery on removable battery device. Actually some phones support case-powerbanks but I can't save battery of powerbank by charging up to 80 percent as I can on rooted device. No power bank percentage, just 4 or 6 partitions. And I lose 25% energy by charging phone via USB from power bank. Unless you can suggest me device with 8Ah or more with non-removable battery.

Comment: @vasik988 So is that 8Ah with the phones integrated battery AND a battery case, or just the phone battery inside? I mean, the iPhone 11 Pro Max with the battery case gets to about 5-6Ah, but I think what you're describing with different partitions, rooting and an available bootloader.